# Key error, and change the data frame in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am getting an error when I use Pandas library. 
For better understanding, I am trying to change the code to make my input data more readable, at the same time one to change the dimension of input.

I had not any problems to run the model when I use 'np.loadtxt' function.

The reason I want to use Pandas is, simply because of using box-cox transformation, for my input data(you can see this data in the following link.) Then input data provides a lot of 0, so that it predicts unexpected minus values on and on.

For that I need to read the 5th column, which is actually precipitation and that is needed to be converted by box-cox transformation. With 'load.txt.' I cannot easily do for this transformation, thus I just want to use Pandas, but it shows key errors.

Could you help me how to solve this problems?

Thank you.

The link for the input text file ->  [Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bnzJrywYR33LhpDZBRw_RaFXmVdvKS7U)

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import boxcox #to deal with the input data(which has a lot of error)

tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.set_random_seed(777)  # reproducibility





def MinMaxScaler(data):

    numerator = data - np.min(data, 0)
    denominator = np.max(data, 0) - np.min(data, 0)
    # noise term prevents the zero division
    return numerator / (denominator + 1e-7)


# train Parameters
seq_length = 36
data_dim = 5
hidden_dim = 8
output_dim = 1
learning_rate = 0.01
iterations = 300




# Open, High, Low, Volume, Close
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', dtype='double', delimiter=',')
df = df.interpolate(method ='linear', limit_direction ='forward')
xy = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
#xy = np.loadtxt('df.txt', dtype='double', delimiter=' ', skiprows=1)
#xy = xy[::-1]  # reverse order (chronically ordered)

# train/test split
train_size = int(len(xy) * 0.7)
train_set = xy[0:train_size]
np.random.shuffle(train_set)

test_set = xy[train_size - seq_length:] # Index from [train_size - seq_length] to utilize past sequence

# Scale each
train_set = MinMaxScaler(train_set)
test_set = MinMaxScaler(test_set)

x=xy[0:4]
y = xy[:: -1] # close as label

# build datasets(window)
def build_dataset(data, seq_length):
  dataX = []
  dataY = []
  for i in range(seq_length):
    dataX.append(data[i:data.shape[0]-(seq_length-i)].reshape(-1, 1, 5))
  dataX = np.concatenate(dataX, axis=1)
  dataY = data[i+1:train_set.shape[0],4].reshape(-1, 1)
  return dataX, dataY

trainX, trainY = build_dataset(train_set, seq_length)
testX, testY = build_dataset(test_set, seq_length)

# input place holders
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, seq_length, data_dim])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# build a LSTM network
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
    num_units=hidden_dim, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)
outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
Y_pred = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    outputs[:, -1], output_dim, activation_fn=None)  # We use the last cell's output

# cost/loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y_pred - Y))  # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# RMSE
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
rmse = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(targets - predictions)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    # Training step
    for i in range(iterations):
        _, step_loss = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict={
                                X: trainX, Y: trainY})
        print("[step: {}] loss: {}".format(i, step_loss))

    # Test step
    test_predict = sess.run(Y_pred, feed_dict={X: testX})
    rmse_val = sess.run(rmse, feed_dict={
                    targets: testY, predictions: test_predict})
    print("RMSE: {}".format(rmse_val))

    # Plot predictions
plt.plot(testY,'b',label='observed')
plt.plot(test_predict,'r',label='predicted')
plt.xlabel("Time Period")
plt.ylabel("Precipitation")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback? One thing I noticed already is that your shared dataframe is not comma-separated as you specify in your `read.csv`-call

Comment: okay I will edit my question!

Comment: hello is there anyone can help me out?